# Get price by month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I need to get the total price per month.

I have

- inited_time (ex. 20160530105130)
- first_payment_price
- deleted

I tried grouping by inited_time

```
SELECT inited_time, DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%c') as month, SUM(first_payment_price) as price
FROM some_table
WHERE inited_time > 0 AND deleted = 0
GROUP BY inited_time
```

But it doesn't sum them together.
ex of result:

```
[
  {
    "inited_time": 20160530105130,
    "month": "5",
    "price": 25000.00
  },
  {
    "inited_time": 20160530105157,
    "month": "5",
    "price": 100000.00
  },
  {
    "inited_time": 20160610000002,
    "month": "6",
    "price": 75000.00
  },
  {
    "inited_time": 20160617000001,
    "month": "6",
    "price": 50000.00
  },
  {
    "inited_time": 20160701000001,
    "month": "7",
    "price": 80000.00
  },
  {
    "inited_time": 20160702000001,
    "month": "7",
    "price": 200000.00
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the type of the `inited_time` column?

Comment: It is big int (20)

Comment: You can't select both the SUM() per Month and at the same time the inited_time: The latter will most likely be different for each record in your month. So what inited_time would you like to get? (allthough Mysql may give you a random one when not in strick mode)

Comment: Could there ever be more than one year present in your data set, and, if so, do you want to report just one month for all years?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thats a good point. I currently do not know that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I Think I need to get for all years there are records available, but still grouped by the month. Then I still need to show the year i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally the `inited_time` column would be a format date or timestamp.  Assuming it is fixed width, we can aggregate by month using division and modulus on this column to isolate the month number:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(inited_time / 100000000) % 100 AS month, SUM(first_payment_price) AS price
FROM some_table
WHERE inited_time > 0 AND deleted = 0
GROUP BY 1;
```

Assuming you might have multiple years in your data set and you would want to report each year month separately, we can try using `STR_TO_DATE` followed by `DATE_FORMAT`:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(inited_time, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'), '%Y-%m') AS ym,
       SUM(first_payment_price) AS price
FROM some_table
WHERE inited_time > 0 AND deleted = 0
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: This seems the best solution. But can you explain the group by 1 and order by 1 ?

Comment: The `1` in `GROUP BY 1` just means group by the first column in the select clause, which is the month or year-month.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the total price per month.

Simply, group by month and remove inited_time from the select clause

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%c') as month, 
        SUM(first_payment_price) as price
FROM   some_table
WHERE inited_time > 0 
AND deleted = 0
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%c');
```

*Edit*. If you have different years included add another condition `DATE_FORMAT(20160530105130, '%Y')`, or if you want only one year even though you have different years filter the needed year on the where clause. For example for 2016 year the condition would be `DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%Y') = 2016`

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%c') as month,
        DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%Y') as year,
        SUM(first_payment_price) as price
FROM   some_table
WHERE inited_time > 0 
AND deleted = 0
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%c'),DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

group by `month`

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(inited_time, '%c') as month, SUM(first_payment_price) as price
    FROM some_table
    WHERE inited_time > 0 AND deleted = 0
    GROUP BY month
```